# Is it possible to print odd and even numbers without using global counter in multi-threaded application

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, global-variables, conditional-statements, mutex

With global counter, we can use mutex(for Owning Resource) and Conditional Variable(For Signaling other thread) in multi-threaded application to print odd and even numbers on-by-one.

But How do we achieve same without using global counter?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is this in C, C++ or some other language?

Comment: I used pthread with C using global counter to write program to print odd, even one-by-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But How do we achieve same without using global counter?

Why do you need a global counter? A way to wait for and signal the other thread is *all* you need.

```
void odd(void *ignore)
{
  for (int j = 1; ; j += 1) {
    printf("%d\n", j);
    // signal other thread
    // wait for it to signal me
  }
}

void even(void *ignore)
{
  for (int j = 2; ; j += 2) {
    // wait for other thread to signal me
    printf("%d\n", j);
    // signal other thread
  }
}
```

Comment: It is achieved without using global counter as well. Thanks